# How to Configure IIS to run a FastCGI application

Tags: django, iis, fastcgi

I am trying to get a django app to run using IIS. These are the versions in use:

```
django: 1.9
python: 2.7
Windows: Server 2016
IIS: 10
```

I am following the directions from this site:

https://www.toptal.com/django/installing-django-on-iis-a-step-by-step-tutorial

I am up to this point `Configuring IIS to run a FastCGI application`

> Click OK on the handler information dialog. IIS will then ask you to
>   confirm the creation of a matching FastCGI application entry which you
>   will need to confirm. This entry will be visible in the FastCGI
>   Settings feature, accessible at the root screen of the IIS Management
>   Console.

But when I go to the CGI settings that application is not listed.

Can anyone offer any advice on what I may be missing or doing wrong or how I can debug this further?

Comment: BTW, Python on IIS is no longer recommended as it brings little benefit to Microsoft Windows/Azure as a whole, so you should switch to Linux if you can. More can be found in https://blog.lextudio.com/shifting-to-azure-app-service-on-linux-b216f4584b03

Comment: This app is normally deployed on linux, but we have some clients that require windows.

Comment: It will be difficult for you to support yourself and the clients on IIS/Windows, if Microsoft has no plan. Hope you can find enough justification to convince your clients to use Linux.

Comment: No, at these sites it is a high level corporate edict. If we cannot run on Widows they will jut not buy the app from us.

Comment: I use [wfastcgi](https://pypi.org/project/wfastcgi/#description). It works alright.

Comment: @Borut, my blog post reveals the status of wfastcgi. Microsoft did open source it, but didn't update it for a long while. Recently Microsoft announced that it is deprecated. So even if it seems to work, you are fully on your own and without any technical support.

Comment: @LexLi, as of now it works and that's good enough. The main thing is that corporate world just isn't as simple as saying our product isn't supported on Windows Server / IIS, get us a Linux machine with Apache. As Larry said, either you make it work on Windows Server / IIS or somebody else will get the job. Well, the good news is that containerization has come to rescue.

Comment: @Borut I am using fastcgi - the issue is what I posted - after I configure the handler the app is not listed.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't use `fcgi.py`, but if the only problem is that application is not listed, you can still manually add it.

Comment: I was finally able to get this working by running this command `New-WebHandler -Name "DjangoFastCGI" -Path "*" -Verb "GET,POST" -Modules FastCgiModule -ResourceType Unspecified -ScriptProcessor "C:\pyt
hon27\python.exe|C:\Repos\CAPgraph\manage.py fcgi --pythonpath C:\Repos\CAPgraph --settings settings"`